Any medical evidence that Upper Respiratory Tract Infections (URTI) temporarily relieve Dry Eye Disease (DED)?
Many patients, who suffer DED, find that URTI's temporarily relieves their DED. Any evidence that backs, and explains, this correlation? I have a couple of theories.
(1) In response to the pathogen, the body produces more mucus, tears, other secretions that relieve DED as a therapeutic side effect.
(2) In response to the pathogen, the body circulates circulating more anti-inflammatory bodies or markers that relieve the inflammation behind DED.
(1) Higher body temperatures, such as from pyrexia, warms the Meibomian Glands and helps express meibum, relieving Meibomian Gland Dysfunction.
(2) The body knows that the patient has enough trouble trying to breathe, so the body ignores allergens that cause DED.

Welcome to Medical Sciences.SE. Questions here are required to demonstrate some degree of prior research on your part, so a great way to address that is for you to cite your sources that say URTIs can temporarily relieve DED for some people. And do you have any sources that led you to your theories?
